# Facebook Sharer.php not working properly

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

We are using facebook.com/sharer.php?u="ourwebsite.com" to share pages.. only problem is, when we try to share pages that have subdirectories, like "ourwebsite.com/blog/," it will share the link "ourwebsite.com/b," and leave out the rest of the url.. any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that probably you are trimming the url, try to encode it before sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

also, use the full URL (add `http://`).

Or just do it in javascript:

```
var sharer_url = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+encodeURIComponent(document.location);
```